# ¿Como pasar un diccionario como Argumento en c#?

Tags: c#, diccionarios

¡Hola mundo!

Estoy aprendiendo C# y en un ejercicio, hay que crear una funcion que imprima los numeros en palabras.

```
Console.WriteLine(traducir([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])) // 
Output: ["cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"]
```

Para lograr esto anterior, cree una lista que el imprime el valor(en este caso "cero", "uno"...) si el key(0,1,2...n+1) existe. La funcion quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Program
                        
{
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] arr  = new int[] {0,1,2};
    traducir(arr);
  }
 
  public static void traducir(string[] arr) {
      
      var arr = new Dictionary<string, int>
      {
        [0] = "cero",
        [1] = "uno",
        [2] = "dos",
        [3] = "tres",
        [4] = "cuatro",
        [5] = "cinco",
        [6] = "seis",
        [7] = "siete",
        [8] = "ocho",
        [9] = "nueve",
      };

      foreach(int key in arr.Key)
      {
        if(key.ContainsKey())
        Console.WriteLine("${key.Value}");
      }
   }
}
```

En cambio, me devolvio el siguiente error:

```
error CS0128: A local variable named `arr' is already defined in this scope
```

Lo que me hace suponer que no pase el diccionario bien como argumento.

Comment: El parametro que recibis se llama igual (exactametne igual!!!) que la variable que creas adentro.. y es lo que dice el error.. cambia el nombre de una de las dos....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay mucho de javascript en tu código, tienes algunos problemas con los tipos, por ejemplo:

```
//así está
public static void traducir(string[] arr)

//así debería ser
public static void traducir(int[] arr)
```

```
//así está
var arr = new Dictionary<string, int>

//así debería ser
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>
```

```
//así está
 [0] = "cero",

//así debería ser
{ 0 , "cero" },
```

Te dejo el código completo

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
    traducir(arr);
}

public static void traducir(int[] arr)
{

    var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 0 , "cero" },
        { 1 , "uno" },
        { 2 , "dos" },
        { 3 , "tres" },
        { 4 , "cuatro" },
        { 5 , "cinco" },
        { 6 , "seis" },
        { 7 , "siete" },
        { 8 , "ocho" },
        { 9 , "nueve" },
    };

    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(item))
            Console.WriteLine($"{dic[item]}");
    }
}
```

Te dejo otro código, usando `switch` en vez de un `Dictionary`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = { 1,2, 3 };
    traducir(arr);
}

public static void traducir(int[] array)
{
    foreach(var item in array)
        Console.WriteLine(traducir(item));
}
public static string traducir(int num) => num switch
{
    0 => "cero",
    1 => "uno",
    2 => "dos",
    3 => "tres",
    4 => "cuatro",
    5 => "cinco",
    6 => "seis",
    7 => "siete",
    8 => "ocho",
    9 => "nueve",
    _ => "desconocido"
};
```